# Is there a simple low-overhead way to install deb packages in a virtual environment?

Tags: apt, chroot, virtualenv

When I'm working on some arbitrary project I usually need a couple of packages. For all the python packages I create a virtualenv so that once I'm done I can delete the whole thing, and it does not fill up my disk and create version conflicts and what not.

But I also usually install a couple of packages with `apt-get`, and unlike the virtualenv, they linger around, fill up my disk, slow down updates, etc. So what I'd like to be able to do is to have a virtualenv for Debian packages.

I'm sure there are ways to do this. You can probably run a VM, a Docker image, or a chroot. But these provide isolation that I don't want, and require basically a whole Debian installation, which is not exactly what I'd want if I'm going to be making lots of them for every project.

All I want is basically a simple script to install Debian packages and their dependencies in a sub-directory and set up the path so that they work.

Answer (score 0):

I developed my own solution for this: http://pepijndevos.nl/2018/06/24/sysenv-virtualenv-for-system-packages.html

It's basically an chroot overlay on top of your root filesystem.